# Understanding the statistical error metric used in this paper

Tags: data-visualization, standard-deviation, error, scatterplot

The research paper ***A network framework of cultural history*** [1] has the following visualization

[image]

It is a scatter plot between the number of births and the number of deaths of notable individuals in different locations across the world. Any point present outside of the two curves are considered outliers. The **m<sub>e</sub>=7** specified in the visualization is described as

> multiples **m<sub>e</sub>** of the square-root-deviation e from the perfectly balanced diagonal

The supplementary materials (Page 13) [3] for the paper gives the following additional information:

[image]

I'm trying to recreate this visualization with a filtered data set.

I have computed the error statistic for all the points in the data set but I don't understand how to connect that and **m<sub>e</sub>**.

Can somebody explain how to draw the two curves in the visualization using the above equation?

I don't have enough reputation to add more than 2 links to the question.
Here are the links to the research papers.

[1] h t t p s://www.uvm.edu/~cdanfort/csc-reading-group/schich-science-2014.pdf

[3] h t t p://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~hwshen/5544/Slides/1240064.Schich.SM.pdf

Comment: Research Paper: https://www.uvm.edu/~cdanfort/csc-reading-group/schich-science-2014.pdf

Comment: Supplementary material (Page 13): http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~hwshen/5544/Slides/1240064.Schich.SM.pdf